# How to determine number of subscribers to an RSS Feed

Tags: wordpress, rss, blogs, subscribe

I have a client that is using the basic feed for their Wordpress site (www.website.com/feed). She is asking how many people are subscribed to her feed. Is there an easy way to do this? I thought you could with Google Reader, but I guess those are only the statistics for Google Reader. I know Feedburner can do that, but will hooking up the feed to feedburner effect how the feed currently works on the site?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to start to use feedburner.

This article lays out some good ways to do that.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_FeedBurner

Using plugins, custom functions, and editing .htaccess files.

Because you already have this setup, I would recommend the .htaccess method.

Ask Apache full details.
http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/redirecting-wordpress-feeds-to-feedburner.html